# Using Lib file alonside DLL (as apposed to function pointers)

Tags: c++, dll

I've always found it a bit of a pain that you have to use LoadLibrary() and define function pointers when wanting to make use of a DLL, it just feels a bit archaic when so much is automated now days. So when I stumbled across a forum post explaining that the VS auto-generated lib file that always (in my experience) gets compiled alonside your DLL can be used to save yourself the hassle, as a sort of auto-import mechanism, I figured I'd put it to the test.

I created two very minimal projects to test this, but it doesn't appear to be working.

The code in its entrirety for the DLL:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) int get10()
  {
    return 10;
  }
}
```

And for the exe (an otherwise empty Win32 console app):

```
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Kernel32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dll1.lib")

__declspec(dllimport) int get10();

int main(int, char**)
{
  int x = 0;

  if (LoadLibrary(L"dll1.dll") != NULL)
  {
    x = get10();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

dll1.dll and dll1.lib are local and visible to the project, but when I go to link it get10() is unresolved. If I remove the call to this it builds and runs and the LoadLibrary() call succeeds.

I also tried copying across the dll1.exp, just clutching at straws really, but that didn't help either.

Is what I'm trying to do actually valid?

By the way I appreciate you'd usually just use a lib file proper, it just grabbed my curiosity for circumstances where you might have these dll and "reduced" lib files but not have the source to compile a regular lib file.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? And why are you still using LoadLibrary?

Comment: It doesn't link. And I'm using LoadLibrary because I figured, well, that it'd still need loading at runtime. As I understood it this auto-generated lib file included only an export table of sorts, not the compiled code.

Comment: No, linking the import library makes your exe depend on that DLL, the loader loads else you get an OS error saying the DLL is not found. If its not linking then something else is wrong, such as mismatched calling convention/linking wrong lib etc - you should post the actual link error and state that is the issue

Comment: Ok I've commented out the LoadLibrary thanks but still the exact same error: int __cdecl get10(void)" (__imp_?get10@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: @whoasked - No, you don't need to call LoadLibrary, your `#pragma comment(lib, "dll1.lib")` should resolve the get10() function for you.  The problem is probably name mangling of the get10() function name.  Open a Visual Studio command prompt, then do a `dumpbin /exports dll1.dll` to see the exact syntax of how your get10() function was exported.  Maybe there is some `_` character or `@` character interspersed with it.

Comment: @David Ching - The outup from what you suggest:
ordinal   hint  RVA      name

1         0     00011005 get10 = @ILT+0(_get10)

Comment: `extern "C"` is your problem.  You put that on the exported function but you forgot that in the import declaration.  Using a .h file so you can't get this wrong is **very** strongly recommended.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'd actually just realised that through trial and error. I would usually have a common header it's just I only did this as a quick test and not having linked that way before it through me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You either link as static, or as dynamic.
So, in essence, you need __declspec(dllexport) only if you're loading the function at runtime by name. Read some of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/03/21/10509670.aspx), for example.

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx), regarding __declspec(dllexport):

> This convenience is most apparent when trying to export decorated C++ function names. Because there is no standard specification for name decoration, the name of an exported function might change between compiler versions. If you use __declspec(dllexport), recompiling the DLL and dependent .exe files is necessary only to account for any naming convention changes.

Comment: unless exporting C functions